# C++ LoadLibrary fails when load dll which generated by vs2010

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, loadlibrary, node-ffi

Firstly, I have a **add.dll** which generated by vs2010 IDE,

add.h:

```
#define _EXPORT
#ifndef _EXPORT
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
EXPORT int add(int a,int b);
```

add.c:

```
#include "add.h"

int add(int a,int b) {

  return a+b;
}
```

And then ,i want to call this add.dll in my another **pdf.c** program:

```
#include "add.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define _EXPORT
// #pragma comment(lib,"add.lib")
// __declspec(dllimport) int add(int a,int b);
typedef int (*DLLFUN)(int a, int b);

DLLFUN fun;

EXPORT int dosome(int a,int b) {
HMODULE hdll = LoadLibrary("add.dll");
if(hdll!=NULL){
    // DLLFUN add = NULL;
    fun=(DLLFUN)GetProcAddress(hdll,"add"); //----here find the add fun

    return fun(a,b);
}
return 0;
```

}
And i build and link this pdf.c with vs2010 tools but not vs2010 IDE itself:

```
cl.exe /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL C:\Users\liz\Desktop\pdfdll\Release\pdf.c /link /DLL /OUT:C:\Users\liz\Desktop\pdfdll\Release\pdf.dll
```

Then a get a **pdf.dll** which i want to call it using **node-ffi** with node.js:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');


var intPtr = ref.refType(ref.types.int);

var libm = ffi.Library(__dirname+'\\pdf.dll', {
'dosome': [ 'int', [ 'int','int' ] ]
});

var a = libm.dosome(1,5); 
console.log(a);
```

As a result, the console.log output 0 which meaning in pdf.c program ,it fails to load the add.dll library.

But what is strange that when i build and link the add.c and add.h using vs2010 tool like above, it print the right answer 6.

So, i have tried to find what this two methods different. I use the **Dependency Walker** to find that the dll build with vs2010 IDE dependent with **MSVCR100.DLL** and **KERNEL32.DLL** while the dll build with cl.exe only dependent with **KERNEL32.DLL**.

In the real situation, i have a more complexer porgram which export a dll and a .h file using VS2010 IDE. I have to do some work to call this dll in my node.js program. Where am i wrong and what can I do ?

Comment: This might help you : In your Visual Studio project goto its properties and check the Command Line pages of Compiler and Linker and compare them with your cl command

Comment: Not that it matters in this case due to your ordering, but `#define _EXPORT` has no business being in your *client* (your `pdf.c` file). Not sure why it is there.

Comment: @WhozCraig this is not important, i think,still thanks.

Comment: @engf-010 sorry i can not find what you say in vs2010 IDE...

Comment: @ZexiLi It would be *incredibly* important if that `#define` were *before* your header include. Which is why I said "Not that it matters in this case due to your ordering" and "Not sure why it is there".

Comment: @ZexiLi: In VS open the Solution Explorer,select your project and choose properties which opens property-pages. Now select C/C++ and select the last item (the Command Line property). This will show the commandline
VS uses to compile you project. Idem for Solution Explorer->Linker.

Comment: @engf-010 I have find this before, and on the top it says "all the options(L)" ,does it mean this is all the optional options but not the options using in this project

Comment: @WhozCraig i include the add.h in my pdf,c and defind  _Export to make the EXPORT values ____declspec(dllexport)

Comment: @ZexiLi: what you see there is the commandline VS uses to compile you project. Its generated from the options choosen in other property-pages. Compare what it says here with what you use in your manual cl invocation. The difference will likely be an omitted -D option.

Comment: @engf-010 Thank you very much. what does the -D option mean? Debug?

Comment: no with -D you define,things like macro's or other definitions like UNICODE which your program can use for text substitution or conditional compilations. Actually VS uses /D instead of -D.

Comment: Maybe `add.dll` is not on the path when `LoadLibrary` is called. Try again, but temporarily copy `add.dll` to `SysWOW64` folder (or `System32` for 64-bit process). It is not enough that two dll's are in the same folder, for target dll to be on the path.

Comment: @ZexiLi: Did you ever figure this out? I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: @Dialecticus: That did the trick! Nice. Basically it is now working with: `LoadLibrary("C:\\Path\\to\\my.dll")`